# Combinatorics and game of bingo

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

2000 dots on placed on a circle and may be colored either black or grey.  If we see 2 black dots next to each other then we say bingo. if we see 2 grey dots are two apart (i.e. one black dot or one grey dot in between) then we also say out loud bingo bingo. What is the minimum number of times we can shout bingo with this constraint.

Comment: If your problem statement is correct, the minimum number is 0, as you can colour all the dots grey. Do you mean "if we see 2 grey dots are two apart (i.e. one black dot OR ONE GREY DOT in between)", which would make the problem more interesting?

Comment: Post your results with a small number of dots (from the answer below). Someone else may see patterns that you may not have seen.

Comment: typo what I meant by 2 grey dots are two apart is one black dot OR ONE GREY DOT in between as mentioned by mcd

Comment: It might be a good idea to add additional context to the question, such as your motivation for asking, or where you found the problem. Otherwise, it's likely this will be closed (which would be a shame, as this is a neat puzzle).

Comment: I agree with @C-RAM : show what you tried, to avert closure of this nice problem.

Comment: Context to this problem is puzzle which I recently stumbled in old math periodical. Nothing more nothing less

Comment: I mean, certainly there's something "more" in that you could do them the kindness of citing the periodical, the issue, and (if possible) the author. (And in the body of your question, not just a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that for $n$ dots the minimum number of bingos is $\lceil \tfrac{1}{4}n \rceil$ (for $n \ge 5$). This is achievable, by using $\lceil\tfrac{1}{4}n\rceil$ pairs of Bs and inserting between them either single or double Gs to make up the total. This is the minimum, because three Gs in a row can always be changed, whatever flanks them, in a way which decreases the number of bingos, so it is never desirable to have more than 2 Gs in a row. Also, GBG, with a single B between two Gs, can always be replaced by BBG or GBB without increasing the number of bingos, so it is never necessary to have a single B to achieve the minimum.